# Number of ultrafilters in the free Boolean algebra on countably many generators

Tags: boolean-algebra

Let $A$ be the free Boolean algebra on denumerably many generators. How many ultrafilter does $A$ contain? How to prove it?

Comment: What are your thoughts about that? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: remember that an ultrafilter on $B$ is essentially the same as a boolean algebra morphism $B\to 2$. How can you characterize morphisms from a free algebra to $2$ ?

Comment: Does that mean thus that $A$ has $2^\omega$ ultrafilters?

Comment: Well what's your proof ?

Comment: Well, since $A$ has denumerably many elements and an ultrafilters is essentially the same as a Boolean epimorphism from $A$ to $2$, then $A$ has $2^\omega$ ultrafilters.

Comment: That's not a correct proof (though the result is correct)

Comment: What would be your argument then?

Comment: You have to compute $|Hom_{Bool}(A, 2)|$, which doesn't only depend on the cardinal of $A$ a priori. But here it does, because $A$ is free on countably many generators, so a morphism $A\to 2$ is essentially an application (set-theoretic) $\omega\to 2$.

Comment: Ah ok, I see. Thanks